# BusinessObjects Formula Syntax

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am writing this formula with BusinessObjects DeskI but it returns syntax error. This is my formula:

```
=IF(length(<Dt_Credit>=0) then <Dt_Credit>=(TODATE("01011900","ddMMyyyy") )    
ELSE <DT_Credit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot wrong with your formula.  Let's break it down:

```
=IF ( length(<Dt_Credit>=0) 
      then <Dt_Credit>= ( 
                           TODATE("01011900","ddMMyyyy") 
                        )    
      ELSE <DT_Credit>
```

First off, you have no closing parenthesis.  Parentheses are not required in an If/Then, so can you just drop the one after `If`.  You also don't need parentheses around the `ToDate` function.  So we have:

```
=IF length(<Dt_Credit>=0) 
 then <Dt_Credit> = TODATE("01011900","ddMMyyyy") 
 ELSE <DT_Credit>
```

Next, you're doing an assignment to the `<Dt_Credit>` object *within* a formula, which is impossible.  So we'll take that out:

```
=IF length(<Dt_Credit>=0) 
 then TODATE("01011900","ddMMyyyy") 
 ELSE <DT_Credit>
```

Next, I'm *assuming* that `<Dt_Credit>` is actually a `Date` object and not a `Number`.  If that's true, then then `Length()` function won't work as it doesn't accept dates as parameters.  If you're testing for a blank `<Dt_Credit>` then you should use `IsNull()` instead:

```
=IF IsNull (<Dt_Credit>) 
 then TODATE("01011900","ddMMyyyy") 
 ELSE <DT_Credit>
```

Finally, I'm assuming that you're using DeskI.  If it's WebI, then the syntax is a little different.  Replace < > with [ ].

Comment: Thank you so much I am very grateful